# Azure Devops IIS web app manage failed with powershell error

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline in Azure Devops that without any changes stop working. The task where my pipeline fails is a "IIS web app manage" task, where I do a AppPool stop
[image]

The error that I get is

```
Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if ([Console]::InputEncoding -is [Text.UTF8Encoding] -and [Console]::InputEncoding.GetPreamble().Length -ne 0) { [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false } if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\azagent\A3\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup_1b2aec60-dc49-11e6-9b76-63056e018cac\0.5.15\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\azagent\A3\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup_1b2aec60-dc49-11e6-9b76-63056e018cac\0.5.15\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup.ps1'''))"'.
```

But the interessting thing is that the App pool is stopped and the pipeline works fine until 2 days ago. No changes on the pipeline and on the destination folder. Recreated also the tragets in the deployment groups.

Thanks for any hint.

**##UPDATE: LOGS**

```
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3350887Z ##[section]Starting: Stop IIS
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3523223Z ==============================================================================
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3523551Z Task         : IIS web app manage
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3523878Z Description  : Create or update websites, web apps, virtual directories, or application pools
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3524171Z Version      : 0.5.15
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3524416Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3524782Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group
2021-09-29T15:43:11.3525169Z ==============================================================================
2021-09-29T15:43:15.0041212Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" stop apppool /apppool.name:"MYHOST"
2021-09-29T15:43:15.0731119Z "MYHOST" successfully stopped
2021-09-29T15:43:15.1615455Z ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if ([Console]::InputEncoding -is [Text.UTF8Encoding] -and [Console]::InputEncoding.GetPreamble().Length -ne 0) { [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false } if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\azagent\A3\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup_1b2aec60-dc49-11e6-9b76-63056e018cac\0.5.15\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\azagent\A3\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup_1b2aec60-dc49-11e6-9b76-63056e018cac\0.5.15\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup.ps1'''))"'.
2021-09-29T15:43:15.1631012Z ##[section]Finishing: Stop IIS

enter code here
```

Comment: can you post more of the step log output? Usually when a script fails you'll see other output, unless you've redirected or suppressed it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [shayki abramczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7409220/shayki-abramczyk), It looks like your IT Team has put some security in the computers that blocked running some PowerShell scripts (maybe only it from remote).

Try to run it in your PowerShell:

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
```

I guess you will get this output:

```
ConstrainedLanguage
```

If yes, try to switch it to  `FullLanguage`:

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = "FullLanguage"
```

If it doesn't help maybe it's also blocked, so you need to talk with IT Team that will change it or try to change the registry like explained  [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/97hk9d/how_do_i_disable_constrained_language_mode/)  or set the environment variable  `__PSLockdownPolicy`  to  `0`.

Please check [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57687378/15997690) for reference

Comment: Oh men your save my life!
With your hint we turned off our Sentinel One Agent and after this it works. Now we will check in detail what is the problem with Sentinel One.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.